# printing a sorted list in class in python

Tags: python

I am trying to display a sorted car list and print it - DisAllCarsSorted().

this is my code (after correction):

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, manufacture, production_year):
        self.manufacture = manufacture
        self.production_year = production_year

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.manufacture, self.production_year)

class CarOwner:

    car_owners = []
    all_cars = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cars = []
        CarOwner.car_owners.append(self)

    def add_car (self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)
        CarOwner.all_cars.append(car)


    def DisAllCars():

        for owners in CarOwner.car_owners:
            for car in owners.cars:
                print(car)

    def DisAllCarsSorted():

        print(sorted(CarOwner.all_cars, key=lambda x: x.manufacture))

print(CarOwner.all_cars)
def DisOwnerCars(car_owner):
    for car in car_owner.cars:
        print(car)

def DisAllOwnerCars():
    for owners in CarOwner.car_owners:
        print('Cars owned by {}:'.format(owners.name))
        for car in owners.cars:
            print(car)        


jane = CarOwner("Jane")
jane.add_car(Car("Mitsubishi", 2017))

bob = CarOwner("Bob")
bob.add_car(Car("Mazda", 2013))
bob.add_car(Car("BMW", 2012))

DisOwnerCars(jane)
DisAllOwnerCars()
CarOwner.DisAllCarsSorted()
CarOwner.DisAllCars()
```

this is the error print:

```
[<__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD358>, <__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD320>, <__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD278>]
```

I understand that this lines are not good:

```
CarOwner.all_cars.append(car)
```

and

```
print(sorted(CarOwner.all_cars, key=lambda x: x.manufacture))
```

but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Is this really the code that's causing problems? Because the line mentioned in the stack trace does not appear in your code.

Comment: @timgeb He does tell Python, right in the call to `sorted`. For me, the code works fine (though it should define `Car.__repr__` to generate meaningful output, and indentation is wrong for two methods)

Comment: It looks like you are using an outdated version of your code in iPython. The code you have posted here works, however it's likely that you started coding in iPython and did not restart it or re-import the relevant modules after updating the code.

Comment: @tobias_k how should I define it to get a better output? (Car.__repr__ whats that)?

Comment: On my system I added the class parts to the call and get no errors: `CarOwner.DisAllCarsSorted()`
`CarOwner.DisAllCars()`

Comment: @Karin it does work now but the print isn't good, see in the code that I change in the Q.

Comment: @terence hill yes I did it now but I get weird print. check for yourself

Comment: `__str__` is what you get when you convert your object to a string or `print`, what you want is to define how the object is represented. define a `__repr__` method that returns a string. You can also just change `__str__` to `__repr__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a correct print:

```
print([ str(x) for x in sorted(CarOwner.all_cars, key=lambda x: x.manufacture) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

> this is the error print:
>
> ```
> [<__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD358>, <__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD320>, <__main__.Car object at 0x0000000009DBD278>]
> ```

Your code works well. What you are seeing is not an error but just the way Python represents instances whose classes do not provide a `__repr__` method. This method is used for representing the instances when printed, e.g. as part of a list.

```
class Car:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Car(%r, %r)' % (self.manufacture, self.production_year)
```

Output:

```
[Car('BMW', 2012), Car('Mazda', 2013), Car('Mitsubishi', 2017)]
```